# .Для матрицы А (m * k) найти номера столбцов, имеющих все нулевые элементы

Tags: vba

Код есть, но он не работает.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim m As Integer, k As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, l As Integer
Dim a() As Integer
m = CInt(txtB.Value)
k = CInt(txtC.Value)
ReDim a(m, k) As Integer
For i = 1 To m
    For j = 1 To k
    a(i, j) = InputBox("Введите элементы a(" & CStr(i) & "," & CStr(j) & ")")
    txtA.Value = txtA.Value & CStr(a(i, j)) & " "
    Next j
txtA.Value = txtA.Value & vbCrLf
Next i
For i = 1 To m
    For j = 1 To k
    If a(i, j).Value = 0 Then
    k = k + 1
    End If
    Next j
    If k = 1 Then
    l = l + 1
    End If
    MsgBox "Номер столбца, где все нули: " & Str(k)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Код есть... Вопрос в чем?

Comment: Код есть, но он не правильный :( Не могу понять, как именно вычислить столбец со всеми нулями

Comment: Явная ошибка: *a(i, j).Value* - Не пишется  *Value*, это массив

Comment: Исправила. Но вопрос остаётся тем же...Как же найти столбец со всеми нулями?

Answer (score 0):

Макрос выводит последовательно сообщения с матрицей и номером столбца, где все нули (*txtA* заменил на *sStr*):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a() As Integer
Dim sStr As String
Dim m As Integer, k As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, l As Integer
'    m = CInt(txtB.Value): k = CInt(txtC.Value)
    m = 2: k = 2

    ReDim a(m, k)

    For i = 1 To m
        For j = 1 To k
            a(i, j) = InputBox("Введите элементы a(" & i & "," & j & ")")
            sStr = sStr & a(i, j) & " "
        Next j

        sStr = sStr & vbCrLf
    Next i

    For j = 1 To k
        l = 0

        For i = 1 To m
            If a(i, j) = 0 Then l = l + 1
        Next i

        If l = m Then MsgBox sStr & Chr(10) & "Номер столбца, где все нули: " & j
    Next j
End Sub
```

1. *Integer* хоть и занимает меньше памяти, но обрабатывается дольше *Long*. Можно заменить.
2. При сцеплении с текстом переводить число в строчный тип не обязательно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень выручили! :)